# Is a gem acts like `bullet` which can automatically detect your query performance and suggest you to add an index on some specific columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jbuilder

I want to speed up my query, I haven't done any index on my tables.

But I have no idea where should I put the index in the right place.

## Controller

```
  def search
    @rooms = Room.includes(:hotel, :skus).where(id: available_rooms_ids)
  end
```

## JSON builder

My JSON builder is kind of complex.

Children need to fetch its parent data.

Patent also needs to fetch its children data as well.

Their relationship chain looks like

- Hotel HAS_MANY Room
- Room HAS_MANY RoomSku
- RoomSku HAS_MANY STOCK

CODE

```
  json.array!(@rooms) do |item|
    json.merge! item.attributes
    json.hotel item.hotel
    json.room_skus do
      json.array! item.skus do |sku|
        next if (sku.date < @check_in_time.to_date or sku.date > @check_out_time.to_date )
        json.merge! sku.attributes.merge({stock:sku.stock})
      end
    end
    json.img_src_url item.hotel.images.last.src.url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [pg_idx_advisor](https://github.com/cohenjo/pg_idx_advisor) to find out what indexes your database needs and then write a migration that will create such indexes.